# A certain store sells $31$ different flavors of ice cream. How many different $3$-scoop cones are possible if :

Tags: probability, statistics

A certain store sells $31$ different flavors of ice cream .How many different $3$-scoop cones are possible if :

a) each flavor must be  different and the order of flavors is unimportant?

$$\frac{31!}{3!28!}$$

b)each flavor must be  different and the order of flavors is important?

$$\frac{31!}{28!}$$

c)Flavors need not be different and the order of flavors is unimportant?(This is a non-trivial question)

$$\frac{31!}{3!30!}$$

d) Flavors need not be different and the order of flavors is important?

$$31^3$$

Could you check it for me please?

Comment: Yes, that looks about right.

Comment: In c) you used Stars and Bars correctly. Alternately one can use a more simple-minded cases approach.

Answer (score 1):

> > a) each flavor must be different and the order of flavors is unimportant?
>
> $31! / 3!(28)!$

Yes. $^{31}C_3$ or $\binom{31}{3}$ counts the ways to select 3 unique items from 31.

> > b)each flavor must be different and the order of flavors is important?
>
> $31! / (28)!$

Likewise, $^{31}P_3$ or $\binom{31}{3}3!$ is the ways to select 3 from 31 and arrange them.

> > c)Flavors need not be different and the order of flavors is unimportant?(This is a non-trivial question)
>
> $33! / 3!(30)!$

Indeed!   The "stars and bars" method counts $\binom{31+3-1}{31-1}$ ways to put $3$ identical items into $31$ distinct boxes - or in this case take $3$ scoops from $31$ tubs.

Alternatively you might have counted the ways to select: three identical scoops, or a pair and a single, or three different scoops. $31+31\cdot 30+\binom{31}{3}$

> > d) Flavors need not be different and the order of flavors is important?
>
> $31*31*31$

Yes, $31^3$ counts the ways to make 3 independent choices with $31$ options each.